# The mysql errors aren't displaying correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am following this tutorial to create the registration database that I am working on. I have been bouncing back and forth by looking back at the video and then looking at comments trying to find a solution to my problem.

The problem that I am having is that the errors are that I have setup are not showing properlly with my database. I have a user with a username entitled, 'lowheartrate' but when I put that in the username field and try to login with it, it tells me one of my other errors,
"We can't find that username. Have you registered?"

Glad that works but I need others to work as well. Specifically the ones that aren't working are the following errors:

```
   The 'user_active' error.  

   The 'user_exists' error.
```

Here is the code affiliated with the problems that I am having:

***My login.php where it shows the code's errors:***
[image]

***The users.php code that connects them together and tells which to do:***
[image]

***The general.php:*** 
[image]

***The init.php :***
[image]

***A better look at the users.php :***

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    return  (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"),0) == 1) ? true : false;
    }

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    return  (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
    }
?>
```

***A better look at the login.php :***

```
<?php
include ('core/init.php');

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($username) == true || empty($password) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password.';
    } else if (user_exists($username) == false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
    } else if (user_active($username) == false) {
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account.';
    } else {
        // here
    }

    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

***A better look at init.php :***

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

***A better look at general.php :***

```
<?php
function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
?>
```

***A better look at connect.php :***

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'lr') or die($connect_error);
?>
```

***A look at the form (login.php widget) :***

```
<div class="widget">    
    <h2>Returning Member?</h2>
    <div class="inner">

        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <ul id="login">
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus  >
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"  >
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" >
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="register.php">Create an Account</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

***Not sure if it matters but here's the index.php where it's being displayed on :***

```
<?php
$pageTitle = 'gLounge - Welcome to gLounge!';
include('includes/php/header.php');
?>

            <!-- Middle content section -->
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-9 content">
                        <h2>Use gLounge42 as your new source to connect with fellow gamers. We have plenty for you to look at.</h2>
                        <p>

                            gLounge42 allows all types of gamers on all types of consoles/platforms connect with each other with 
                            unlimited amount of reasons to do so. Here at gLounge42 you can chat with them and go as far as posting 
                            in forums to get members for you Call of Duty clan. Possibilities are endless so go ahead and get your 
                            account setup now with gLounge42!

                        </p>
                        <div class="to-tutorial">   
                            <p><strong>Register an Account to get started:</strong></p>
                            <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-success">Register</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Includes the login widget on the top right side of page -->
                <?php include('includes/widgets/login.php');?>
                    <!-- Includes the side navigation area --> 
                <?php include('includes/php/sideNavigation.php');?>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php
include('includes/php/footer.php')
?>
```

***The elements of the database that I am using :***

[image]

***The users that are connected to the database :***

[image]

If any more information is needed please let me know.
Best regards,
Codi

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I am still getting the same errors when I replaced the 3 '=' signs with 2 instead. Not picking up the user_active unfortunately

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Yes still have not found my solution. Would LOVE your input please

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 When I add the code you gave me and proceed to the login.php it does not have any error codes what so ever which isn't a good thing because I proceeded to the login.php without even putting in a username or password and it did not give me an error code.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 With the following code you gave me going under the user_exists section of the users.php I got the same errors. Nothing really has changed.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Just finished posting all the code, sorry about that ;p

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 All done (: Even put the index.php in there haha

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thank you for all of your help! Speak to you soon. It is 3am here so I will go get a bottle of soda so I don't fall asleep. haha really do not want to go to bed yet as I would hate to wake up to this problem too xD Thanks again

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Hello again Arif :P I have put the code you told me to in my connect.php and the users.php and I receive no errors when I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);//I change this line always use this. During 
//the production. after you finish you can change it. 

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

Read the comment, where ever you found them in the answer. 
**Connect.php**

```
<?php
//Your were mixing the mysqli and mysql, here you are using mysqli_ function But method you are 
//using msysql one so change it to mysql function



$connect_error = 'Sorry we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('lr',$con) or die($connect_error);//Database name should be first
?>
```

**users.php**

```
<?php

require 'database/connect.php';//You were missing connection here.
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize ($username);
    echo $username;
    //$result=or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"))==1)        return TRUE; else     return FALSE;
    //if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query()== 1)) 
    }

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize ($username);
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active`='1'" ))==1)        return TRUE; else     return FALSE;    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all stop using mysql. Use mysqli_* function with prepared statements or PDO.

Your if statement in login.php looks fine. Try to use this in user.php:

```
$bool = (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("your query")) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Now you're checking the amount of rows that had been returned. And i'm not sure if you can put an if statement in a return. So now you do:

```
Return $bool;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Sorry I just do not want to screw this up anymore. Do I put the $bool = (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("your query")) == 1) ? true : false; on the top row or the bottom one!? and where do you want to me to put the Return $bool; ?? If you can give me line #'s that would be great!

Comment: Put $bool = (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("your query")) == 1) ? true : false; above THE return statement in user.php and replace your existing return statement with return $bool

Comment: I currently have two return statements, What I am confused about is where to put each and currently I am not getting any errors or anything showing up when I get directed to the login.php - It is just white with no content what so ever.

Comment: Try before you ask. Replace all your return statements in user.php with the code i gave you.